# adding to a manytomany field in django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I am trying to save a many to many tags field when creating a post.

this is my post request to create a new post

```
{
"name":"testpost1",
"caption":"test caption n",
"tags":[{"name":"tag1"}]
}
```

Models

```py
class Tags(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="created_tags")
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="following_tags")
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Posts', related_name='tags', symmetrical=True)


class Posts(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
```

The serializer for Post and tag

```py
class TagsSerializerMini(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ('name', )

class PostsSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    tags = TagsSerializerMini(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'caption', 'tags', 'num_reactions', 'num_comments', 'created_by',  'posted_time',
                  'updated_time', )
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'posted_time', 'updated_time', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags', [])
        post = Posts.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag in tags_data:
            t, _ = Tags.objects.get_or_create(name=tag["name"], created_by=self.context['request'].user)
            t.posts.add(post)
        return post
```

Now the issue is, when i am addding a post to tag `t.posts.add(post)` it is throwing an Error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`. I tried adding a post from the shell also, its giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got similar problem and I solved it by using an intermediary model (using [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)), here is how should look your code:

**models.py:**

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    # ...
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Posts', related_name='tags', symmetrical=True, through='PostsTag')


class PostTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tags)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts)
```

**serializer:**

```
# ...
def create(self, validated_data):
    tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags', [])
    post = Posts.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for tag in tags_data:
        t, _ = Tags.objects.get_or_create(name=tag["name"], created_by=self.context['request'].user)
        PostTag.objects.create(tag=t, post=post)  # <----- Create m2m relation
    return post
```

Note: I didn't tested the code, but hope this helps!